# Is there any way to have different collation for multiple different databases on a Single PostgreSQL server?

Tags: postgresql, collation

I am setting up a new PostgreSQL server on Windows which has multiple databases with different collation.

I have one Japanese client and other one is English but, I have only one server. Is there any way to achieve this in PostgreSQL?

I tried it on Linux and it worked well but on Windows i am unable to do so.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: invalid locale name: "ja_JP.UTF8". This is the error i get when trying to create database with Japanese locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a database with a different collation on PostgreSQL on Windows like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE nippon
   ENCODING UTF8
   LC_COLLATE japanese
   LC_CTYPE japanese
   TEMPLATE template0;
```

You need to specify the Windows locale names, and you have to use `template0` if you want to create a database with a different collation.

Comment: Thanks, @laurenz your solution worked for me. Where can i get Windows locale names?